# php driver mongodb , never loaded

Tags: php, mongodb, dll, driver

I have installed MongoDB, wamp server and I have added a collection in MongoDB

I then downloaded the php_mongo-1.6.8.zip from [S3](https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html) -> OK

There are many files in the zip file, but which one is the one I need? (Window 10 64 bit)

I found my `php.ini` location from `phpinfo()` in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini` and I inserted this string in `extension=php_mongo.dll`. In c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/ copy (for test) the php_mongo-1.6.8-5.6-vc11.dll (renamed in php_mongo.dll).

I can restart apache without errors and call mongo.php in my host

```
echo extension_loaded("mongo") ? "mongo loaded\n" : "mongo not loaded\n";
echo "<br>";
echo extension_loaded("mysql") ? " mysql loaded\n" : " mysql not loaded\n";
```

This is the print:

> mongo not loaded
>
> mysql loaded

Why isn't the mongo driver loading?

Comment: in php_error.olog i find
[30-Aug-2015 19:35:34 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_mongo.dll' - Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato. in Unknown on line 0

But in the folder "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext" I HAVE THE php_mongo.dll !!!!!!!!! help help

Comment: in phpinfo find "Compiler:MSVC11", the wamp is a 64bit version, but if i use "php_mongo-1.6.1-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll" don't work

Comment: i i use "php_mongo-1.6.1-5.6-vc11.dll" the php error it's not present, but the mongo it always not loaded!!
maybe there are these drivers and mongodb takes for all the nose :D

**What is the solution!!!???where is the problem!!??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is the API compile version. With the version 1.4.5 mongodb driver now all work fine.

**the correct driver for my Window 10 64 bit and Wamp64bit is php_mongo-1.4.5-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll**

Answer (score 0):

solution for driver php version 1.6.11

1. download a new version (i have 5.5.12 into wamp server) php (i have downloaded 5.5.29) from php.net
2. update wamp for use new php version
3. download the 1.6.11 driver php (dll for me) [PECL-mongodb](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.6.11/windows)

**Very important choose correct VC9 or VC11 and 32 or 64 bit**